# Agrupar soma por mês e ano

Tags: query, select, firebird

Tenho uma tabela simples em um banco de dados FIREBIRD:

```
idCliente: integer    
dataPagamento: date
valor: numeric
```

Como fazer um select que some todos os valores a pagar, agrupando pelo mês e ano?

tipo assim:

`select MES_ANO, sum(valor) from pagamento group by MES_ANO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução para banco de dados Firebird.

```
select 
  extract(MONTH from dataPagamento) AS MES,
  extract(YEAR from dataPagamento) AS ANO, 
  sum(valor) 
from pagamento 
group by extract(MONTH from dataPagamento),extract(YEAR from dataPagamento)
```

Comment: função desconhecida `TO_CHAR`

Comment: Foi mal, confundi com Oracle, estou corrigindo, a função é date_format. Vou editar a resposta

Comment: desculpa cara, erro meu... é que estou trabalhando com dois bancos de dados aqui. o banco correto é firebird

Comment: Para extrair Mes e ano no Firebird é esse comando extract(MONTH from dataPagamento) AS MES,    extract(YEAR from dataPagamento) AS ANO,